# Pass string to main and break up into array

Tags: c, arrays, character, c-strings

I am passing arguments to main with this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
        int i = 1;

        for(i = 1; i < argc; i++)
                printf("%c", argv[i]);

        return 0;
}
```

So I use `./test 218 abc 392990xFF[w2 dlx` which works fine. However, the array is:

```
arr[1] = "218"
arr[2] = "abc"
arr[3] = "392990xFF[w2"
arr[4] = "dlx"
```

I want the array to be like this:

```
arr[0] = '2'
arr[1] = '1'
arr[2] = '8'
arr[3] = 'a'
etc...
```

How can I achieve this without putting a space after each digit or character?

Comment: arr[0] will not holds "218"

Comment: Yea, sorry. arr[1] does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The arguments passed by the run time environment to the program can be captured by `main` using `int argc, char** argv` only. If you have a need to combine them into one large array, you'll need to write the code for that, or print them one character at a time.

```
int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    int i = 1;
    int j;
    int len;

    for(i = 1; i < argc; i++)
    {
       len = strlen(argv[i]);
       for ( j = 0; j < len; ++j )
       {
          printf("%c", argv[i][j]);
        }
     }
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: @R Sahu Can I modify this, so the white spaces are in there as well?

Comment: Never mind, I figured it out. Just change `len = strlen(argv[i]);` to `len = strlen(argv[i]) +1;`.

Answer (score 2):

First of all this is not what it will print -

```
    arr[0] = "218"
    arr[1] = "abc"
    arr[2] = "392990xFF[w2"
    arr[3] = "dlx"
```

`argv[0]` will store  `./test`. And `"218"` will be on index `1` thus others similarly .

And also `printf("%c", argv[i]);` .`%c` expects a `char` and you pass a string which is incorrect.

Solution could be -

```
   #include <stdio.h>

  int main(int argc, char ** argv)
    {
       int i = 1,j;

       for(i = 1; i <argc; i++)
           for(j=0;argv[i][j]!='\0';j++)
              printf("%c\n", argv[i][j]);

       return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Not sure why the downvotes. Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: @yayu  Well  no problem . Cheers !!

Answer (score 1):

Determine the total number of characters in all of the strings, then allocate a new character array of that length, and then copy the input characters into the new array.

The last part could take advantage of the sizes you gather in the first part: have an outer loop over all the argument strings, with an inner loop over the characters in each string.

**EDIT**: Now that I'm not on a mobile device, here's the above in code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    //For storing sizes of each input string
    int *arg_chars;
    //Where the individual characters are stored
    char *stored_chars;

    /* Determine total number of characters, and store
       characters in each word for later re-use */
    arg_chars = malloc(argc * sizeof(int));
    int total_chars = 0;
    //Loop starts at 1 since we don't care about arg 0
    for(int i=1; i<argc; i+=1)
    {
      arg_chars[i] = strlen(argv[i]);
      total_chars += arg_chars[i];
      printf("Word %d is %d long\n", i, arg_chars[i]);
    }

    /* Load argument characters into the stored_chars array */
    stored_chars = malloc(total_chars * sizeof(char));
    int current_char = 0;
    //Loop starts at 1 to exclude the program name (arg 0)
    for(int i = 1; i < argc; i+=1)
    {
      printf("Scanning word %d (%s):\n", i, argv[i]);
       for(int j = 0; j < arg_chars[i]; j+=1)
       {
          stored_chars[current_char] = argv[i][j];
          printf("  Stored letter %d `%c` (letter %d of word %d)\n", current_char, argv[i][j], j, i);
          current_char += 1;
       }
    }

    /* Demonstrate that it's all loaded and accessible in any order */
    for(int i=total_chars-1; i >= 0; i-=1)
    {
      printf("stored_chars[%d] = `%c`\n", i, stored_chars[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

> ### Output:
>
> ```
> Word 1 is 3 long
> Word 2 is 3 long
> Word 3 is 12 long
> Word 4 is 3 long
> Scanning word 1 (218):
>   Stored letter 0 `2` (letter 0 of word 1)
>   Stored letter 1 `1` (letter 1 of word 1)
>   Stored letter 2 `8` (letter 2 of word 1)
> Scanning word 2 (abc):
>   Stored letter 3 `a` (letter 0 of word 2)
>   Stored letter 4 `b` (letter 1 of word 2)
>   Stored letter 5 `c` (letter 2 of word 2)
> Scanning word 3 (392990xFF[w2):
>   Stored letter 6 `3` (letter 0 of word 3)
>   Stored letter 7 `9` (letter 1 of word 3)
>   Stored letter 8 `2` (letter 2 of word 3)
>   Stored letter 9 `9` (letter 3 of word 3)
>   Stored letter 10 `9` (letter 4 of word 3)
>   Stored letter 11 `0` (letter 5 of word 3)
>   Stored letter 12 `x` (letter 6 of word 3)
>   Stored letter 13 `F` (letter 7 of word 3)
>   Stored letter 14 `F` (letter 8 of word 3)
>   Stored letter 15 `[` (letter 9 of word 3)
>   Stored letter 16 `w` (letter 10 of word 3)
>   Stored letter 17 `2` (letter 11 of word 3)
> Scanning word 4 (d1x):
>   Stored letter 18 `d` (letter 0 of word 4)
>   Stored letter 19 `1` (letter 1 of word 4)
>   Stored letter 20 `x` (letter 2 of word 4)
> stored_chars[20] = `x`
> stored_chars[19] = `1`
> stored_chars[18] = `d`
> stored_chars[17] = `2`
> stored_chars[16] = `w`
> stored_chars[15] = `[`
> stored_chars[14] = `F`
> stored_chars[13] = `F`
> stored_chars[12] = `x`
> stored_chars[11] = `0`
> stored_chars[10] = `9`
> stored_chars[9] = `9`
> stored_chars[8] = `2`
> stored_chars[7] = `9`
> stored_chars[6] = `3`
> stored_chars[5] = `c`
> stored_chars[4] = `b`
> stored_chars[3] = `a`
> stored_chars[2] = `8`
> stored_chars[1] = `1`
> stored_chars[0] = `2`
> ```

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't quite understand what you mean.

Comment: Essentially the same thing as what R Sahu said, but instead of processing each character with `printf("%c", argv[i][j])` you would use `stored_chars[k] = argv[i][j]; k+=1`. And you would need to have declared `stored_chars` to be a character array with the appropriate size to hold all those characters.

Comment: Ahh ok, that makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: I've updated my answer with full code, including some comments and see-what-it's-doing output lines.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than a `for` loop, you can also simply use pointers and `while` loops instead. There are generally many ways to solve problems in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    int i = 1;
    int j = 0;

    while (i < argc) {
        char *p = argv[i];
        while (*p) {
            printf (" arr[%2d] = \"%c\"\n", j++, *p);
            p++;
        }
        i++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
$ ./bin/argvchars 218 abc 392990xFF[w2 dlx
 arr[ 0] = "2"
 arr[ 1] = "1"
 arr[ 2] = "8"
 arr[ 3] = "a"
 arr[ 4] = "b"
 arr[ 5] = "c"
 arr[ 6] = "3"
 arr[ 7] = "9"
 arr[ 8] = "2"
 arr[ 9] = "9"
 arr[10] = "9"
 arr[11] = "0"
 arr[12] = "x"
 arr[13] = "F"
 arr[14] = "F"
 arr[15] = "["
 arr[16] = "w"
 arr[17] = "2"
 arr[18] = "d"
 arr[19] = "l"
 arr[20] = "x"
```

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful. I like learning multiple ways to do things.

Comment: That is what makes C such a robust language. There are usually several ways to tailor the code to exactly what you need. Sometimes many ways. Here we simply assign a pointer to the beginning of each command line argument and print each character while advancing the pointer until the null-terminating character `'\0'`(or just `0` - numerically the same) is found at the end of each argument. Then we just advance to the next argument and do it again until we run out of arguments. For the most part it eliminates worrying about indexes.